# How to dynamically manipulate a component in React?

Tags: reactjs

I want to distribute a component that can be dynamically manipulated by developers, such as the following:

- Being able to insert an element after/before one of its elements
- Being able to delete its elements
- Being able to replace its element with an element

One of my coworkers have suggested me the following approach:

```
<Book>
  {builder => builder
    // Assume that the keys are initially defined inside of the component
    .appendAfter('title', <h2>Foobar</h2>) 
    .appendBefore(...)
    .replace('foo', <Bar />)
  }
</Book>
```

I am not sure if it’s a good approach because

1. The component is not self-descriptive.
2. The component is against React’s principals, that we should not manipulate the DOM directly. (Although it’s the Virtual DOM)

How would you implement this component?

Edited: I'd like to avoid defining props receive a component like `afterSomethingComponent`, `beforeSomethingComponent` since there is a bunch of components inside.

Comment: check this it may help you https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-3zpcxk

Comment: @Jayavel There are many components inside and I think it's going to be really hard to manage if I should define props like `beforeSomeComponent` and `afterSomeComeponent`. Do you think is there any other approach without using props?

Answer (score 0):

You can try React.Fragment (React v16.2.0+)

```
import React from 'react'
class Book extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {this.props.before}
        {this.props.children}
        {this.props.after}
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

usage:

```
<Book before={<h2>before element</h2>} after={<h2>after element</h2>}>
  <h1>ELEMENT</h1>
</Book>
```

by following the principle of React, user can pass children, before, after props to control what they what to render

and by using React.Fragment, it can render multiple elements without wrapping them within a